# duplicate pages HTTP and HTTPS in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

When my site is crawled it comes up with duplicate pages one being HTTP and the other HTTPS and have no idea how to fix the issue in wordpress any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to force users to use either HTTP or HTTPS, but not both if you want nice clean search results.  The `Force SSL Everywhere` plugin ( http://wordpress.org/plugins/force-ssl-everywhere/ ) should force SSL to be used no matter what.

On this note you should do also the same with subdomains.  You should all redirect users who request `www.yourdomain.com` to `yourdomain.com` or vice-versa or to whatever the Wordpress `site_url` is set to so that there is no ambiguity between the naked domain and the `www` subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here on serving a different robots.txt file via HTTPS.

http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/3411545.htm

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the solution for your problem is setting a proper redirection of HTTP to HTTPS urls. For this you need to add a few lines to your .htaccess code.

If you are having **Apace** or **LiteSpeed hosting** try the one below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

For **Nginx** type **hosting**

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;
 return 301 https://www.yourdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

If you still didn't get it right I recommend to read [**Move WordPress Website from HTTP to HTTPS \ SSL | Guide**](http://www.techwibe.com/wordpress-http-to-https-ssl-guide/)